# xcopy not working the same as ctrl+c/ctrl+v in W10?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-10

I'm trying to write a batch file in Window 10 that will copy a folder to overwrite the C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy folder. So I do

```
xcopy /y /e C:\Backup\GroupPolicy %systemroot%\system32\
```

and it says it copied all the files. But if I check the group policy using gpedit, my changes aren't there. But if I select the C:\Backup\GroupPolicy folder in the file explorer and use ctrl+c and then go to c:\Windows\System32 and do ctrl+v and say yes to the prompt to overwrite the files, when I check gpedit, my changes are there now. When I do it through the GUI, I do get a prompt saying I need admin permissions to copy the folder, so I'm wondering if xcopy is not being given proper admin permissions even though I'm running it from an administrative command prompt.

Comment: Have you tried the `/u` switch?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean when you say "my changes aren't there".

If your ACL information is missing, then I think you're missing a switch:

```
/O           Copies file ownership and ACL information.
```

You might also be hitting 32/64 bit environment problems and actually be looking for `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue was related to permissions. xcopy has some flags like /o /k /r /h that also copy the metadata of the file. Tried that and got permission denied. Then I found that I could use robocopy instead with the /copy:DATSO (/copyall also gave a permission denied error) flag and that worked.